# The inverse mapping theorem for normed spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, inverse, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $(X, \vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_X )$ and $(Y, \vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert_Y )$ be normed vector spaces and $T \in L(X, Y)$ a linear and continuous operator. Show that if $T$ is open and injective, then $X$ and $Y$ are topologically isomorphic.

I have: if $T$ is open and linear, then it is also surjective, i.e. bijective. Then I have to show that $T^{-1}$ is continuous. I would use the inverse mapping theorem, but $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily Banach spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have worked out that $T$ must be surjective we know that $T$ must be a bijection and so there exists a linear map $T^{-1}:Y \to X$ that is inverse to $T$. It remains to see that $T^{-1}$ is continuous.

By the topological characterisation of continuity, we need to show that if $O$ is open in $X$ then $T(O) = (T^{-1})^{-1}(O)$ is open in $Y$. This is immediate since $T$ is an open map. Hence $T$ is continuous which is what we wanted to prove.